# In which cases user.verificationStatus can be verified/unverified?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I have created a project in google action with account-linking enable.
and it is working fine on the test simulator and android device.
But not working well with Google Nest Mini when I am trying to link my account to the project. And it is because of **user.verificationStatus != VERIFIED** same account used while on android and it was working.

In easier terms :

When testing with android device : **user.verificationStatus == VERIFIED** (with google account example@gmail.com). It means account is verified

When testing with Google nest mini : **user.verificationStatus != VERIFIED** (with google account example@gmail.com). It means account is not verified.

How the same account can have two verification status?

Can anyone tell me in which circumstances **user.verificationStatus** verified or unverified?.

Any information regarding **user.verificationStatus** would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verification status is a signal that the developer can use as a signal before using any API for specific users like [user storage](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-user). As the [documentation mentions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-user#expiration_of_user_storage_data), there are several possible reasons the end-user may be seen as a `GUEST`:

- If the user has turned off Personal Results for Assistant
- If they have Web & App Activity turned off
- If Voice Match on the device did not match
- The user isn't signed in on the device

The `VERIFIED` means that the current session is connected to an identified Google account based on signals from the user account and the device. It isn't tied to your account alone.

Comment: It is working now but

- Web & activity was turned on.
- In my case Google Home application says your device does not support voice match (Nest Mini)
- user was signed in otherwise I would not be able to test my project on device.

I think it was only because Personal Results were turned off (At least in this case).

Thanks for efforts :)

Comment: In my case, "Web and App Activity" was enabled but inside it "Include Chrome history and activity from sites, apps and devices that use Google services" was disabled. Once I enable that, `VERIFIED` is `true`. This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807425/issue-google-action-user-verificationstatus-always-returns-unverified#comment123738927_69955376