# Issue google action user.verificationStatus always returns unverified

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant, actionbuilder

I'm using action builder to create actions. it was all fine when I deployed the action a few months ago,( everything was working those days). but a few days ago when I checked the action it was not working properly.

i find that it always returns (**user.verificationStatus != "VERIFIED"**) true (guest user),according to the [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2#check_if_the_user_is_verified_and_start_the_account_linking_flow) we should only redirect to account linking when the (**user.verificationStatus == "VERIFIED"**) is true

my action only work after account linking so I have set the scene like this(user.verificationStatus != "VERIFIED") ==> end.conversation

(user.verificationStatus == "VERIFIED") ==> accountlinking

It always returns an '**unverified**'/ '**guest**' user so the action never starts.

I checked all the conditions in [Expiration of user storage data](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-user?hl=el#expiration_of_user_storage_data) with multiple accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason is that there is "Save audio" or "Save history for applications and devices" disabled for your Google Account. Go to [the settings page](https://myactivity.google.com/activitycontrols?settings=search&pli=1) and enable them.

Comment: I found the reason, your answer was helpful thanks.
reason: "Web and App Activity" was enabled but inside it "Include Chrome history and activity from sites, apps and devices that use Google services" was disabled